# Can x- ( $ \frac x 2 + \frac x 4$ ) be a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I was confused whether it is a polynomial or not because most of the polynomials which I see don't have brackets like this.

Comment: Parentheses, please.  Did you mean $\frac 1{2x}$ or $\frac 12 \cdot x?$  It changes the answer.

Comment: Try expanding the brackets/braces and simplifying the expression and seeing what happens

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to write

$$x-\left(\frac12x+\frac14x\right)=x-\frac34x=\frac14x=\frac x4$$

then yes: it **already** is a polynomial.

If one of the $\,x\,$ within the parentheses was meant to be in the denominatior then no, it can't be a polynomial by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. According wikipedia polynom is:

> an expression constructed from variables ...and constants...using only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative integer exponents.

given $f(x)=x-(0.75x)=\frac x 4$ is a polynom since you only use addition and substraction and the exponent  $1>0$.your constant is zero and the degree of the polynom is one. that's why the function is a polynom (parentheses does not change wether its a polynom or not).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x - \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{4}\right)&= x - \left(\frac{2x}{4} + \frac{x}{4}\right)\\
&= x - \left(\frac{2x + x}{4}\right)\\
&= x - \frac{3x}{4}\\
&= \frac{4x}{4} - \frac{3x}{4}\\
&= \frac{4x - 3x}{4}\\
&= \frac{x}{4}\end{align}

And $\frac{1}{4}x$ is a polynomial of the first degree. So yes, it is a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

After simplifying, it would equal $x/4$, which is a polynomial(kind of). Technically it is a monomial.

Comment: Thanx every1! your answers helped me!!!! :D