# Can $(\frac{1}{4} t^{2} + \frac{1}{2} t +200) – \frac{2}{3} t$ be a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I know that the expression inside the brackets is a polynomial but when the expression outside the brackets is combined with it, can it be considered a polynomial?

Comment: As in my comment to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426931/can-x-frac-x-2-frac-x-4-be-a-polynomial) is $2/3t$ supposed to be $\frac 23t$ or $\frac 2{3t}$?  Parentheses, please!  The answer depends on this in exactly the same way as that question.  If you understood that, you wouldn't need to ask this one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will still be a polynomial. Collecting like terms, we have:
$$
\left(\dfrac{1}{4}t^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}t + 200\right) - \dfrac{2}{3}t = \dfrac{1}{4}t^2 - \dfrac{1}{6}t + 200
$$
In general, (adding or subtracting or multiplying) any two polynomials will result in another polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of two polynomials is a polynomial.